# Borrow two mutable values from the same HashMap

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

fn populate_connections(
    start: i32,
    num: i32,
    conns: &mut HashMap<i32, HashSet<i32>>,
    ancs: &mut HashSet<i32>,
) {
    let mut orig_conns = conns.get_mut(&start).unwrap();
    let pipes = conns.get(&num).unwrap();

    for pipe in pipes.iter() {
        if !ancs.contains(pipe) && !orig_conns.contains(pipe) {
            ancs.insert(*pipe);
            orig_conns.insert(*pipe);
            populate_connections(start, num, conns, ancs);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

The logic is not very important, I'm trying to create a function which will itself and walk over pipes.

My issue is that this doesn't compile:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*conns` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:10:17
   |
9  |     let mut orig_conns = conns.get_mut(&start).unwrap();
   |                          ----- mutable borrow occurs here
10 |     let pipes = conns.get(&num).unwrap();
   |                 ^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
...
19 | }
   | - mutable borrow ends here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*conns` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:16:46
   |
9  |     let mut orig_conns = conns.get_mut(&start).unwrap();
   |                          ----- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
16 |             populate_connections(start, num, conns, ancs);
   |                                              ^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
19 | }
   | - first borrow ends here
```

I don't know how to make it work. At the beginning, I'm trying to get two `HashSet`s stored in a `HashMap` (`orig_conns` and `pipes`).

Rust won't let me have both mutable and immutable variables at the same time. I'm confused a bit because this will be completely different objects but I guess if `&start` == `&num`, then I would have two different references to the same object (one mutable, one immutable).

Thats ok, but then how can I achieve this? I want to iterate over one `HashSet` and read and modify other one. Let's assume that they won't be the same `HashSet`.

Comment: Also of interest is the [multi_mut](https://github.com/golddranks/multi_mut) crate, which provides a ```get_mut_pair()``` and several other methods for having multiple mutable references to the hashmap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can change your datatypes and your function signature, you can use a `RefCell` to create [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html):

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

fn populate_connections(
    start: i32,
    num: i32,
    conns: &HashMap<i32, RefCell<HashSet<i32>>>,
    ancs: &mut HashSet<i32>,
) {
    let mut orig_conns = conns.get(&start).unwrap().borrow_mut();
    let pipes = conns.get(&num).unwrap().borrow();

    for pipe in pipes.iter() {
        if !ancs.contains(pipe) && !orig_conns.contains(pipe) {
            ancs.insert(*pipe);
            orig_conns.insert(*pipe);
            populate_connections(start, num, conns, ancs);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Note that if `start == num`, the thread will panic because this is an attempt to have both mutable and immutable access to the same `HashSet`.

#### Safe alternatives to `RefCell`

Depending on your exact data and code needs, you can also use types like [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) or one of the [atomics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/index.html). These have lower memory overhead than a `RefCell` and only a small effect on codegen.

In multithreaded cases, you may wish to use a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html).

Comment: Yes I will add another condition to make sure its not happening (start == num). Thank you for help!

Answer (score 10):

## Use `hashbrown::HashMap`

If you can switch to using hashbrown, you may be able to use a method like [`get_many_mut`](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/latest/hashbrown/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_many_mut):

```rust
use hashbrown::HashMap; // 0.12.1

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(1, true);
    map.insert(2, false);

    dbg!(&map);

    if let Some([a, b]) = map.get_many_mut([&1, &2]) {
        std::mem::swap(a, b);
    }

    dbg!(&map);
}
```

As hashbrown is what powers the standard library hashmap, this is also available in nightly Rust as [`HashMap::get_many_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_many_mut).

## Unsafe code

If you can **guarantee** that your two indices are different, you can use unsafe code and avoid interior mutability:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn get_mut_pair<'a, K, V>(conns: &'a mut HashMap<K, V>, a: &K, b: &K) -> (&'a mut V, &'a mut V)
where
    K: Eq + std::hash::Hash,
{
    unsafe {
        let a = conns.get_mut(a).unwrap() as *mut _;
        let b = conns.get_mut(b).unwrap() as *mut _;
        assert_ne!(a, b, "The two keys must not resolve to the same value");
        (&mut *a, &mut *b)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(1, true);
    map.insert(2, false);

    dbg!(&map);

    let (a, b) = get_mut_pair(&mut map, &1, &2);
    std::mem::swap(a, b);

    dbg!(&map);
}
```

Similar code can be found in libraries like [multi_mut](https://crates.io/crates/multi-mut).

This code tries to have an abundance of caution. An assertion enforces that the two values are distinct pointers before converting them back into mutable references and we explicitly add lifetimes to the returned variables.

You should understand the nuances of unsafe code before blindly using this solution. Notably, **[previous versions of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53146512/6) were incorrect**. Thanks to @oberien for finding the unsoundness in the original implementation of this and proposing a fix. [This playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d396290ecb215fb00027f7dd1e547c39) demonstrates how purely safe Rust code could cause the old code to result in memory unsafety.

An enhanced version of this solution could accept an array of keys and return an array of values:

```rust
fn get_mut_pair<'a, K, V, const N: usize>(conns: &'a mut HashMap<K, V>, mut ks: [&K; N]) -> [&'a mut V; N]
```

It becomes more difficult to ensure that all the incoming keys are unique, however.

---

Note that this function **doesn't** attempt to solve the original problem, which is vastly more complex than verifying that *two* indices are disjoint. The original problem requires:

- tracking *three* disjoint borrows, two of which are mutable and one that is immutable.
- tracking the recursive call

  - must not modify the `HashMap` in any way which would cause resizing, which would invalidate any of the existing references from a previous level.
  - must not alias any of the references from a previous level.

Using something like `RefCell` is a *much* simpler way to ensure you do not trigger memory unsafety.

Comment: You actually only need the last line to be in the `unsafe` block, the rest can be moved before it.

Comment: @PeterHall technically that's correct, but I tend to be of the school of thought that the `unsafe` block should encompass all of the code that makes the code actually safe.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that this completely solves OP's problem (even if it answers the title question) because his example code needs to borrow the `HashMap` mutably again, which won't work if he just updates his code to use your function like this: `let (mut orig_conns, mut pipes) = get_mut_pair(conns, &start, &num);`

Comment: @PeterHall no, it wasn't intended to, but I forgot to state that directly. Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: @Shepmaster yes, note that on the OP I've also added a link to the [multi_mut](https://github.com/golddranks/multi_mut/blob/master/src/lib.rs) crate, which includes methods for mutating 2/3/x amount of references to a HashMap

Comment: The `get_many_mut()` method is now supported by nightly: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/97601

Comment: This code is UB. Not language UB, but library UB. If `HashMap` was using `Box` or references, any creating any `&mut` reference while another one is already active (like you do with `get_mut()` twice) would be language UB. Since it uses raw pointers, this is not language UB (and Miri cannot detect it), but the standard library is free to change the implementation so that it will cause language UB.

Comment: `get_many_mut()` is now available in stable rust: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_many_mut

Comment: @MaciejS your link says "This is a nightly-only experimental API."

Comment: @shepmaster, you're right, I missed something, it's still experimental.