# Access two mutable references from a Global hashmap at once in Rust

Tags: rust, hashmap, refcell

Say we have a globally accessible hashmap of trait objects we make with [lazy_static](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.4.0/lazy_static/): `MY_ANIMALS:  Mutex<HashMap<i32, AnimalBox>>`, where `type AnimalBox = Box<dyn AnimalExt+Send>`

Now, we want the animals in this global hashmap to interact with each other. For example, one `AnimalBox` can `AnimalExt::eat(&mut self, prey: &mut AnimalBox)` another.

The problem is that our `eat()` function requires both a mutable reference to self, as well as a mutable reference to the pray (because we want the pray to `AnimalExt::perish(&mut self)` when it's eaten.

However, getting two mutable references to our hashmap causes a `WouldBlock` Error:

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::collections::HashMap;

//type alias for our boxed animals
type AnimalBox = Box<dyn AnimalExt+Send>;

//globally accessible hashmap for keeping track of our animals throughout the scope of our application
lazy_static! {
    static ref MY_ANIMALS: Mutex<HashMap<i32, AnimalBox>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
}

//simple trait for our animals
trait AnimalExt{
    //eat() function requires a mutable reference to another AnimalBox
    fn eat(&mut self, pray: &mut AnimalBox);
    fn perish(&mut self);
    fn energy(&self)->i32;
    fn id(&self)->i32;
}

struct Wolf{
    id: i32,
    energy: i32,
    alive: bool,
}
impl AnimalExt for Wolf{
    fn id(&self)->i32{
        self.id
    }
    fn eat(&mut self, pray: &mut AnimalBox) {
        pray.perish();
        self.energy+= pray.energy()
    }
    fn energy(&self) ->i32 {
        self.energy
    }
    fn perish(&mut self){
        self.alive = false; 
    }
}
impl Wolf{
    pub fn new(id: i32)->Self{
        Wolf{
            id: id,
            energy: 50,
            alive: true,
        }
    }
}
struct Cow{
    id: i32,
    energy: i32,
    alive: bool,
}
impl Cow{
    pub fn new(id: i32)->Self{
        Cow{
            id: id,
            energy: 100,
            alive: true,
        }
    }
}
impl AnimalExt for Cow{
    fn id(&self)->i32{
        self.id
    }
    fn eat(&mut self, pray: &mut AnimalBox) {
        pray.perish();
        self.energy+= pray.energy()
    }
    fn energy(&self) ->i32 {
        self.energy
    }
    fn perish(&mut self){
        self.alive = false; 
    }
}
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    //define our animals
    let cow1 = Box::new(Cow::new(1)) as AnimalBox;
    let cow2 = Box::new(Cow::new(2)) as AnimalBox;
    let wolf1 = Box::new(Wolf::new(3)) as AnimalBox;
    let wolf2 = Box::new(Wolf::new(4)) as AnimalBox;

    //insert them into the global hashmap
    MY_ANIMALS.lock().unwrap().insert(cow1.id(), cow1);
    MY_ANIMALS.lock().unwrap().insert(cow2.id(), cow2);
    MY_ANIMALS.lock().unwrap().insert(wolf1.id(), wolf1);
    MY_ANIMALS.lock().unwrap().insert(wolf2.id(), wolf2);

    //getting one animal to eat() another causes a WouldBlock error
    match (MY_ANIMALS.try_lock().unwrap().get_mut(&0), MY_ANIMALS.try_lock().unwrap().get_mut(&1)){
        (Some(a1), Some(a2))=>{
            a1.eat(a2);
        }
        _=>()
    }
}
```

Is there a good work around for this? Or is there no safe way to do this with a hashmap? I've [seen this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47773849/borrow-two-mutable-values-from-the-same-hashmap) to a similar question, but the suggested answer suggests using `RefCell`, which is incompatible with lazy_static's `Send` trait requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Borrow two mutable values from the same HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47773849/borrow-two-mutable-values-from-the-same-hashmap)

Comment: @kmdreko I linked to this answer in my question. The problem is the ```RefCell`` requirement, and I'd prefer avoiding unsafe code (although I understand if this is not really a practical wish). Could we just swap out the RefCell they are using for a Mutex?

Comment: After reading the answer in detail I see they do suggest using a Mutex in cases where thread safety is needed, so I guess this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the [muti_mut](https://github.com/golddranks/multi_mut) crate, which provides several methods for having multiple mutable references to a HashMap or BTreeMap.

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use multi_mut::{HashMapMultiMut, HashMapMutWrapper};

//type alias for our boxed animals
type AnimalBox = Box<dyn AnimalExt+Send>;

//globally accessible Hashmap for keeping track of our animals throughout the scope of our application
lazy_static! {
    static ref MY_ANIMALS: Mutex<HashMap<i32, AnimalBox>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
}

//simple trait
trait AnimalExt{
    //eat() function requires a mutable reference to another AnimalBox
    fn eat(&mut self, pray: &mut AnimalBox);
    fn perish(&mut self);
    fn energy(&self)->i32;
    fn id(&self)->i32;
}

struct Wolf{
    id: i32,
    energy: i32,
    alive: bool,
}
impl AnimalExt for Wolf{
    fn id(&self)->i32{
        self.id
    }
    fn eat(&mut self, pray: &mut AnimalBox) {
        pray.perish();
        self.energy+= pray.energy()
    }
    fn energy(&self) ->i32 {
        self.energy
    }
    fn perish(&mut self){
        self.alive = false; 
    }
}
impl Wolf{
    pub fn new(id: i32)->Self{
        Wolf{
            id: id,
            energy: 50,
            alive: true,
        }
    }
}
struct Cow{
    id: i32,
    energy: i32,
    alive: bool,
}
impl Cow{
    pub fn new(id: i32)->Self{
        Cow{
            id: id,
            energy: 100,
            alive: true,
        }
    }
}
impl AnimalExt for Cow{
    fn id(&self)->i32{
        self.id
    }
    fn eat(&mut self, pray: &mut AnimalBox) {
        pray.perish();
        self.energy+= pray.energy()
    }
    fn energy(&self) ->i32 {
        self.energy
    }
    fn perish(&mut self){
        self.alive = false; 
    }
}
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    //define our animals
    let cow1 = Box::new(Cow::new(1)) as AnimalBox;
    let wolf1 = Box::new(Wolf::new(2)) as AnimalBox;
    let before_eating_cow = wolf1.energy();
    //insert them into the global hashmap
    MY_ANIMALS.lock().unwrap().insert(cow1.id(), cow1);
    MY_ANIMALS.lock().unwrap().insert(wolf1.id(), wolf1);


    //use get_pair_mut method from the multi_mut crate
    match MY_ANIMALS.try_lock().unwrap().get_pair_mut(&1, &2){
        Some((hunter, prey))=>{
            dbg!("hunter eats prey");
            hunter.eat(prey);
        }
        None=>()
    }
    let after_eating_cow = MY_ANIMALS.lock().unwrap().get(&1).unwrap().energy();
    assert_ne!(before_eating_cow, after_eating_cow);
}
```